# Python pickle: Unclear "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pickle

While using `pickle.load(...)`, there's a possibility that `AttributeError: can't set attribute` is raised. However on a bigger pickle file this error doesn't help at all (because I have no idea what causes it).

Are there any ways to get more information or to debug this? If there are any other advices how to deal with this problem, I would be glad to hear them!

---

The error originally comes from [Jedi's](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/blob/parser/jedi/cache.py#L272) parser branch. The issue is caused by the latest changes in `jedi.parser.fast`. If you want to see the error, you need to run `python test/run.py on_import 100` twice.

---

### Edit - Cause:

```
>>> X.y = 3
>>> class X():
...  @property
...  def y(self): pass
... 
>>> X().y = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

The cause is this AttributeError that gives you no information. Combine that with an inheritance of `__slots__` and properties in the inherited object + pickle and you get this unclear error.

I still think that it's pickle's fault. I'm going to leave this question open, because I still haven't found a way to debug it properly. Pickle should take that `AttributeError` and modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dill` has pickle debugging tools in `dill.detect`.  I can't see what object you'd like to debug as your code above is not due to `pickle`… but I can show an example below, regardless.

```
>>> class Test(object):
...   def __init__(self, x, y):
...     self.x = x
...     self.y = y
... 
>>> x = (i for i in range(10))
>>> y = iter(range(10))
>>> 
>>> t = Test(x,y)
>>> 
>>> import dill
>>> dill.detect.errors(t)
PicklingError("Can't pickle <type 'listiterator'>: it's not found as __builtin__.listiterator",)
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(t) 
<__main__.Test object at 0x1086970d0>
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(t, 1)
{'__hash__': <method-wrapper '__hash__' of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__setattr__': <method-wrapper '__setattr__' of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__reduce_ex__': <built-in method __reduce_ex__ of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, 'y': <listiterator object at 0x108890d50>, '__reduce__': <built-in method __reduce__ of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__str__': <method-wrapper '__str__' of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__format__': <built-in method __format__ of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__getattribute__': <method-wrapper '__getattribute__' of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__delattr__': <method-wrapper '__delattr__' of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__repr__': <method-wrapper '__repr__' of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__dict__': {'y': <listiterator object at 0x108890d50>, 'x': <generator object <genexpr> at 0x108671f50>}, 'x': <generator object <genexpr> at 0x108671f50>, '__sizeof__': <built-in method __sizeof__ of Test object at 0x1086970d0>, '__init__': <bound method Test.__init__ of <__main__.Test object at 0x1086970d0>>}
>>> dill.detect.trace(True)
>>> dill.dumps(t)
T2: <class '__main__.Test'>
F2: <function _create_type at 0x10945c410>
T1: <type 'type'>
F2: <function _load_type at 0x10945c398>
T1: <type 'object'>
D2: <dict object at 0x10948b7f8>
F1: <function __init__ at 0x108894938>
F2: <function _create_function at 0x10945c488>
Co: <code object __init__ at 0x108873830, file "<stdin>", line 2>
F2: <function _unmarshal at 0x10945c320>
D1: <dict object at 0x1085b9168>
D2: <dict object at 0x10947e910>
D2: <dict object at 0x108898910>
T4: <type 'listiterator'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#...snip...
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'listiterator'>: it's not found as __builtin__.listiterator
>>>
```

I couldn't think of a case where there's an `AssertionError` from a `pickle.dump` off the top of my head... but the above debugging tools should work exactly the same way in that case.

If you post a simple reproducible object (i.e. standard lib preferably) that produces an AttributeError on pickling, I'll update my example.

Comment: Nice. I was looking for something like this :-) Still, I think the std lib is lacking.